# При нажатии escape видеоплеер выходит из полноэкранного режима неверно

Tags: javascript, html

Здравствуйте! У меня уже был вопрос по поводу видеоплеера — там мне помогли с ним. Но тут образовалась еще одна проблема:

При переходе в полноэкранный режим срабатывает функция `enterFullScreen()` а при нажатии кнопки выхода срабатывает функция `exitFullScreen()`. При переходе в полноэкранный режим к блоку `<div class="videoControls"></div>` добавляется класс `fullscreen`, а при выходе из полноэкранного режима этот класс убирается.

Проблема вот в чем: Когда в полноэкранном режиме нажимаешь клавишу `esc`, то класс `fullscreen` у `div` не убирается. Пробовал вот так:

```js
window.onkeypress = function(o){
"use strict;";
   if(o.keyCode === 27){
   exitFullScreen();}
};

window.onkeydown = function(o){
"use strict;";
   if(o.keyCode === 27){
   exitFullScreen();}
};
```

Но ничего не вышло. А вот код функции `exitFullScreen()`:

```js
function exitFullScreen(){
"use strict"; 
 if(document.cancelFullScreen){
  document.cancelFullScreen();}
 else if(document.webkitCancelFullScreen){
  document.webkitCancelFullScreen();}
 else if(document.mozCancelFullScreen){
  document.mozCancelFullScreen();}
 else if(document.oCancelFullScreen){
  document.oCancelFullScreen();}
 else if(document.msCancelFullScreenn){
  document.msCancelFullScreen();}
    document.getElementsByClassName("videoControls")[0].classList.remove("fullscreen"); 
    fullscreenHider.style.display = "none";
 fullScreenToggler.style.display = "inline-block";}
```

Спасибо за любую помощь. Вот весь fiddle если нужно: https://jsfiddle.net/0dpp4ng5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо класса пропробуйте использовать псевдо-класс [:fullscreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen)

```
div:-moz-full-screen {
    background: red;
}

div:-webkit-full-screen {
    background: red;
}

div:-ms-fullscreen {
    background: red;
}

div:fullscreen {
    background: red;
}
```

Так-же можно использовать обработчик события выхода из полноэкранного режима:

```
if (document.addEventListener)
{
    document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', exitHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', exitHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', exitHandler, false);
    document.addEventListener('MSFullscreenChange', exitHandler, false);
}

function exitHandler()
{
    if (document.webkitIsFullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.msFullscreenElement !== null)
    {
         document.getElementsByClassName("videoControls")[0].classList.remove("fullscreen");    
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Вариант с JS работает, но при переходе в полноэкранный режим не появляется панель управления плеером.

Comment: @EugenEray Если у Вас возник новый вопрос, задайте его при помощи кнопки «[Задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Если нужно указать контекст, дайте ссылку на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо Crantisz! Немного поменял код и сработало для меня:

```js
function exitHandler(){
"use strict";
  if (document.webkitIsFullScreen === false || document.mozFullScreen === false || document.msFullscreenElement === false){
   document.getElementsByClassName("videoControls")[0].classList.remove("fullscreen"); 
    fullscreenHider.style.display = "none";
 fullScreenToggler.style.display = "inline-block";}
}
```